# Plugin.InAppBilling InAppBillingPurchase.PurchaseToken is sometimes null in production

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I'm using James Montemagno's `Plugin.InAppBilling` library for Xamarin to do iOS and Android in-app subscriptions. It has worked mostly correctly so far, except that once in a while, on iOS only, `InAppBillingPurchase.PurchaseToken` comes back null from calls to `PurchaseAsync` and `GetPurchasesAsync`.

For example, in my Restore Purchases logic, I have code similar to this:

```
var purchases = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.Subscription);

// Sometimes we receive purchases with no PurchaseToken.
// Can't verify the purchase without a token.
var verifiable = purchases.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.PurchaseToken));
```

At this point, `verifiable` sometimes has a different count (0) than `purchases` (1).

So far, this has seemed to happen when the user purchased using either **store credit** or a **gift card**, and only on iOS.

Also, I'm not sure if this bears on the problem, but I am not using the overloads of `PurchaseAsync` and `GetPurchasesAsync` which take `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase`, because I use server-side verification exclusively (no client-side verification). My workflow is to make the purchase, add the resulting `InAppPurchase` object to a queue for processing, and then send it to our server as a separate step, for validation and association with the user's account. However, if this is not a valid workflow or **if it is known that sometimes PurchaseToken data will be available via `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase.VerifyPurchase` but not attached to the `InAppBillingPurchase` objects returned from the methods above**, I would certainly like to know about that. (For what it's worth, I've read the documentation and don't see anything that suggests this.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think I might be on to something. Looking at the source code for Plugin.InAppBililng, it appears that if you do not specify an implementation of IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase when you call PurchaseAsync, your only access to the receipt data comes from the now-deprecated SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt field. In contrast, the code that calls IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase.VerifyReceipt sends in the receipt data found in the app bundle, which appears to be the way Apple currently recommends you get that data. Still investigating...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I've learned enough to provide useful information for anyone else dealing with this issue.

First, I've figured out what Apple means by "iOS 6 style" and "iOS 7 style" receipts. These do **not** refer to the version of iOS that creates the receipts. (My up-to-date iOS 12 device still can and does generate "iOS 6 style" receipts.) Instead, these refer to two different receipt formats that were *introduced* in the respective iOS versions.

- iOS 6 style receipts come from `SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt` and contain information about one specific transaction. This field is now **deprecated** by Apple.
- iOS 7 style receipts come from the app bundle, via the location named in `NSBundle.mainBundle.appStoreReceiptUrl`. These receipts contain a full manifest of all purchases ever made by the user. The receipts don't expire either -- you can always send them to Apple for validation  (though, obviously, individual transactions contained within might show as expired in the response). These are the receipts you should prefer.

The reason this is important is that if you're using the `Plugin.InAppBilling` library, the `InAppBillingPurchase` object you get from calling something like `PurchaseAsync` contains the deprecated iOS 6 style receipt in its `PurchaseToken` field.

I'm still not sure why it is sometimes present and sometimes null, but seeing as the underlying source of the data is deprecated, it's probably safe to assume that this can and will happen. Therefore, it probably makes sense to cut over to the iOS 7 style receipts as soon as possible.

Note that when you call `PurchaseAsync`, if you specify an implementation of `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase`, your `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase.VerifyPurchase` method will receive the newer iOS7 receipt instead. However, the `InAppBillingPurchase` object returned by `PurchaseAsync` still gets an iOS 6 style receipt (if it gets anything at all).

Personally, I like the `InAppBillingPurchase` object itself. It has useful information packed into a convenient package. Since I want to keep the serialized `InAppBillingPurchase` objects in a queue so that I can retry validation if there are problems with our servers, connectivity, etc, what I'm doing is **immediately replacing the `PurchaseToken`** property with the iOS 7 style receipt that I manually retrieve from the bundle.

If you do this, be sure that your code handles the slightly different formats of the iOS 6 and iOS 7 receipts properly. (Our earlier attempts had some errors stemming from not properly understanding what these terms meant.)

I hope this is useful to someone out there. Good luck!